# PHP filter_has_var vs empty?

Tags: php, isset

i know that empty is a bit faster then isset, but filter_has_var is a bit faster then isset (in php.net it written) so what is faster empty or filter_has_var ?

Comment: why don't you benchmark them and let us know the results.

Comment: i did it and it looks that filter is better, but not always correct works

Comment: i didnt make it pure, in my system via caching pasting this method in different places ,also in cycles, it gives addition about 3-5%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter_has_var()`](http://php.net/filter_has_var) might be useful if the superglobals have been purged for some reason, because it checks the original input data, not $_GET, $_POST, $_ETC.

For example:

```
$_GET["injected"] = 123;

var_dump( filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "injected") );   // false

// or the other way round
```

While you can overwrite the variable, the `filter` extension accesses a separate copy. And `INPUT_GET` will not alias to the `$_GET` superglobal.

Apart from that another reason is to use it for unification. If you use filter_var extensively, than a ruleset would be more fond of using filter_has_var() over isset().

But don't use one or the other because of any silly performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`filter_has_var` and `empty` are two totally different functions that do totally different things.  You would not want to swap the use of these two functions.

`empty` is actually a language construct that checks if a variable is considered empty to PHP: for example `null`, `array()` or `''` are considered empty.

`filter_has_var` simply checks one of the PHP superglobals: `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV` or `$_COOKIE` to ensure that a variable was passed with a request.  This function will still return true if the var is empty.

Comment: The PHP function `filter_has_var()` does not check one of the PHP superglobals. It checks the raw input source of the data that the superglobals get their data from.